# Entity Framework 6.1.0 SaveChangesAsync

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous

I have EF helper class that saves changes async:

```
public async Task<int> SaveOrUpdateAsync<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
        where TEntity : class, IContextEntity
    {
        if (entity.Id == 0)
            context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
        else
        {
            TEntity dbEntry = context.Set<TEntity>().Find(entity.Id);
            if (dbEntry != null) dbEntry = entity;
        }

        return await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

public void Save()
{
Task saveEntit1Async = repository.SaveOrUpdateAsync<Entity1>(entity1);
Task saveEntity2Async = repository.SaveOrUpdateAsync<Entity2>(entity2);
Task saveEntity3Async =  repository.SaveOrUpdateAsync<Entity3>(Entity3);

Task.WaitAll(saveEntit1Async, saveEntity2Async, saveEntity3Async);

string test = "test";
)
```

The call gets stuck on

```
Task.WaitAll(saveEntit1Async, saveEntity2Async, saveEntity3Async);
```

line and never gets to

```
 string test = "test";
```

But if I run it as:

```
public void Save()
{
repository.SaveOrUpdateAsync<Entity1>(entity1);
repository.SaveOrUpdateAsync<Entity2>(entity2);
repository.SaveOrUpdateAsync<Entity3>(Entity3);

string test = "test";
)
```

It works fine, all changes are being saved and it gets to

```
string test = "test";
```

Why is

```
Task.WaitAll(saveEntit1Async, saveEntity2Async, saveEntity3Async);
```

Freezes up the operation and never passes call to the next line of code (string test = "test";) ?

Comment: without Task.WaitAll, the system doesn't block the current thread of execution and the next line gets executed, with Task.WaitAll, the current thread will wait untill all the operations are done, then string test = 'test'; gets executed

Comment: Right! But why call gets stuck on WaitAll forever! and never gets to the second line?

Comment: you might have an exception in the task, which might never returns so it will wait forever

Comment: You're probably getting deadlocked in the database or hitting some other error. I don't think context is designed to be used from multiple threads as you may end up sharing a database connection. Also, you need to Attach() you updated entity to the context, not just replace the reference as you're doing with dbEntry = entity;

Comment: But without Task.WaitAll everything updates fine in database.

Comment: Even if just 1 line "repository.SaveOrUpdateAsync<Entity1>(entity1).Wait();" that line never gets passed.

Comment: Have a look at your codeplex question...

Comment: "Multiple active operations on the same context instance are not supported. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context." - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220070(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: If you're in an ASP/GUI setting you cannot use Task.Wait() or it's siblings. This will block the request/gui thread, meaning that when the async operation completes, it cannot give control back to the request/gui thread, thus deadlocking your application. If you're gonna use `async`, use it all the way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I figured it out!

Here is the problem that was happening, when, you wait on the Task with the "Wait" method or take the result directly from the "Result" property of the Task, you block the main thread
at the same time. When eventually the Task completes inside that method (SaveOrUpdateAsync(TEntity entity)) in the thread pool, it is going to invoke the continuation to post back to the main thread (as it never left it), because SynchronizationContext.Current is available and captured. But here is a problem: the  main thread is blocked by "Wait" method and that is how I was getting a deadlock!

To fix deadlock issue I had to specify to not to continue on captured context for context.SaveChangesAsync().

```
public async Task<int> SaveOrUpdateAsync<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
        where TEntity : class, IContextEntity
    {
        if (entity.Id == 0)
            context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
        else
        {
            TEntity dbEntry = context.Set<TEntity>().Find(entity.Id);
            if (dbEntry != null) dbEntry = entity;
        }

        return await context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
    }
```

Comment: Not even using Task.Wait, just await and still had the problem. This snippet fixed my code. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps I'm being stupid (!), but why does your code say

```
if (dbEntry != null) dbEntry = entity;
```

surely that if statement should be

```
if (dbEntry == null) dbEntry = entity;
```

I guess the C# null-coalescing operator would also work to replace both lines

```
TEntity dbEntry = context.Set<TEntity>().Find(entity.Id) ?? entity;
```