# SaveChangesAsync() method not updating database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a web application with:

- Entity Framework **6.1.3**
- Framework .NET **4.5.1**

I made an upgrade of .NET Framework from version **4.5.1** to **4.6.2**.

Since that, the "SaveChangesAsync()" of "System.Data.Entity" method does not updating my database anymore.

I can not find if it's because of the .NET framework package or some compatibility issues between Entity Framework 6.1.3 and .NET Framwork 4.6.2 for "SaveChangesAsync()" method... I'm a lost!

Here's some samples:

**Service class**

```
public async Task<MyActionResponseModel> UpdateSomething(Catalogue catalogue)
{
    if (catalogue== null) throw new ArgumentNullException("catalogue is null");
    var response = new ActionAddResponse();

    var catalogueToUpdate = await _catalogueRepository.GetCatalogueById(catalogue.Id);
    var myDate = new DateTime();
    if (catalogue.EndDate != null)
    {
        myDate = catalogue.EndDate.Value;
        myDate = myDate.Date.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59);
    }

    catalogueToUpdate.Year = catalogue.Year;
    catalogueToUpdate.StartDate = catalogue.StartDate;
    catalogueToUpdate.EndDate = catalogue.EndDate!= null ? myDate : catalogue.EndDate;
    catalogueToUpdate.Tax = catalogue.Tax;
    catalogueToUpdate.Online = Convert.ToBoolean(catalogue.Online);
    catalogueToUpdate.RefNote = catalogue.RefNote;

    await _unitOfWork.SaveAsync();

    response.Success = true;
    response.Message = string.Format("Catalogue has been update");

    return response;
}
```

**UnitOfWork class**

```
public class UnitOfWork:IUnitOfWork
{    
    public async Task SaveAsync()
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); // System.Data.Entity
    }
}
```

**package.config**

```
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.6" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.6" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
</packages>
```

I already checked my async/await choregraphy and everything seems correct.
So what is happening right there?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework 6.1.0 SaveChangesAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867997/entity-framework-6-1-0-savechangesasync)

Comment: It depends a lot of why you hiding through `// some works` comment. Can you show us the part of the code taht updates the entities?

Comment: Try enabling EF logging.  You will be able to see the exact SQL that is being generated.

Comment: I updated my code sample

Comment: Make sure the instance returned by the method `GetCatalogueById` is using the same DbContext as your UoW. Also check you're not using AsNotTracking on it.

Comment: It seems you were right about the instance. Apparently I have two differents instance. I'm trying to figure out what is happening here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what I was doing wrong.
In fact I'm using "Unity" (verison 5.8.6). I made an update of my Unity package at the same time as the .NET Framework last time.

I made my UnityConfig.cs like this:

```
public static void ConfigureUnityContainer(IUnityContainer container)
{
    // some other resgistration
    container.RegisterType<MyEntities>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager());
}
```

The error is on the type of the manager. The correct one is **`PerRequestLifetimeManager`**:

```
public static void ConfigureUnityContainer(IUnityContainer container)
{
    // some other resgistration
    container.RegisterType<MyEntities>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
}
```

What I understood for **`PerRequestLifetimeManager`** is that the container will resolve the same one instance of the object in http request while **`PerResolveLifetimeManager`** will mark the type so that instances are reused across the build-up object graph.

In summary, with **`PerRequestLifetimeManager`**, in different http requests we will have different resolved objects.