# SaveChangesAsync method doesn't save changes (environment troubles)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an issue with my environment.
The question is looks the same with the few another questions:
[SaveChangesAsync() method not updating database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50762560/savechangesasync-method-not-updating-database)
[Entity Framework 6.1.0 SaveChangesAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867997/entity-framework-6-1-0-savechangesasync)

But there is other problem. In my case this code worked a few years, and I'm sure that the issue related to the Database, not this code, so please help with any idea about my environment.

Maybe should I check smth about my db-user\db ?
Also I have a few other servers with absolutely the same code that works fine.

My code:

```
public static async Task SaveResultsAsync(HbTestResult result)
{
    using (var data = new HbContex())
    {
        data.HbMonitor.Add(result);
        Logger.Instance.Error($" point 1 ");
        try
        {
            Logger.Instance.Error($"point 2");
            await data.SaveChangesAsync();
            Logger.Instance.Error($"point 3");
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Logger.Instance.Error($"Ex_Db1.3: {exception.Message} and inner - chain: { ExceptionUtil.GetInnerExceptionsChainAsString(exception)}.");
        }
    }
}
```

I call it in another method:

```
private async Task<bool> PerformTestingAndGetAllResults(HbTest test, ConfigModel notificationConfig, Constants.TestStatus status)
{
    //**** (some variables declaring etc)
    var i = 0;
    while (i < numberOfTests)
    {
        await PerformTesting();
        if (!test.TestStatus.IsValid && test.TestStatus.Status == stat)
        {
            numberOfFailedTests++;
        }
        await DbUtil.SaveResultsAsync(SetTestResultsForDb());
        i++;
    }
    return numberOfFailedTests > notificationConfig.FailuresAllowed;
}
```

Well, also I don't have debug on this machine, so I have to use approaches with logging (but I have full access to DB if it can help.

My code alsways get "point 2" in the `SaveResultsAsync` method, but never get "point 3". And at the same time there is no thrown exception... it looks like thread just freezed or smth like that.

With credential from `connectionString` I'm able to do any operations with my database manually (using `ssms`).

> env: 2012 R2 Standart , IIS 6.2, MSSQL db.

Comment: The linked questions don't point to a specific issue. If you check the linked questions you'll see they were both developer errors. In one case, the wrong package was used. In another, the code was deadlocking itself.

Comment: Use Activity Monitor or SQL Server's (which version by the way?) Profiler or Extended events to see what's currently running on the server and whether the statements were executed. It could be that the SQL commands are blocked and waiting for other commands, or that they just take too long. Calling `SaveChangesAsync` for each individual record results in a huge delay because a new query has to be executed for each record. Why not just add all records to the context and call SaveChangesAsync once?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 13.0.4001.0 64-bit. Ok. thanks, will see how to use profiler and let you know

Comment: You may be able to enable logging in EF 6.1 itself. [by adding a DatabaseLogger interceptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/config-file#logging-database-operations-to-a-file-ef61-onwards) in web.config. This could show more details about what's really happening on the client side

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @PanagiotisKanavos . I've implemented the EF6 interceptor and got the problem. The issue was: error 1827, limit (10240 MB) of the license for create database\alter datebase operations. I don't know why entity don't throw it as common exception but it was in logs like:

> -- Executing asynchronously at 10/3/2018 2:50:42 PM +05:30
>   -- Failed in 20 ms with error: Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.table'.'PK_table' in database
>   'dbname' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create
>   disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the
>   filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting
>   autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.

so, helpful was links: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/config-file#logging-database-operations-to-a-file-ef61-onwards and http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/database-command-interception.aspx

so, final code is:
1) web.config

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
    <interceptors>
      <interceptor type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DatabaseLogger, EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
          <parameter value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data\LogOutput.txt"/>
          <parameter value="true" type="System.Boolean"/>
        </parameters>
      </interceptor>
    </interceptors>
  </entityFramework>
```

2) and this class at any place:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MobileConnectHM.Utils
{
    public class EFCommandInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor
    {
        public void NonQueryExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
        {
            LogInfo("NonQueryExecuted", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText));
        }

        public void NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
        {
            LogInfo("NonQueryExecuting", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText));
        }

        public void ReaderExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
        {
            LogInfo("ReaderExecuted", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText));
        }

        public void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
        {
            LogInfo("ReaderExecuting", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText));
        }

        public void ScalarExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
        {
            LogInfo("ScalarExecuted", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText));
        }

        public void ScalarExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
        {
            LogInfo("ScalarExecuting", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText));
        }

        private void LogInfo(string command, string commandText)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Intercepted on: {0} :- {1} ", command, commandText);
        }
    }
}
```